# changing a span text into input text

Tags: javascript

I have a `table` with `tr, tds` and span inside the td, so i want to reach the text inside the span so i can change it to input when I click an edit button
That's what i tried so far, but it doesnt work:

```
function editRow(clickedButton){

    var getTR = clickedButton.closest('tr');
    var getLength = getTR.childElementCount;
    var getTds = getTR.querySelectorAll("td")

    for (i=0;i<=5;i++) {
        if(i < (getLength-1)) {
            var spanText="";
            spanTexts = getTds[i].getElementsByTag('span');
            spanTexts[i].innerHTML = "<input  type='text' value='"+getTds[i].innerHTML+"'>";
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: i think you should respond on answer given to you...

Answer (score 0):

After comments below and discussion in another answer - I THINK this is what is wanted

Assuming the table looks like this

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="button" value="edit" /></td>
            <td><span>Row 1 Column 1</span></td>
            <td><span>Row 1 Column 2</span></td>
            <td><span>Row 1 Column 3 Span 1</span><span>Row 1 Column 3 Span 2</span></td>
            <td><span>Row 1 Column 4</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This code should do it

```
function editRow(clickedButton) {
    var getTR = clickedButton.parentElement.parentElement;
    var getTds = getTR.querySelectorAll("td")

    for (var i = 0; i <= getTds.length; i++) {
        spans = getTds[i].querySelectorAll('span');
        for(var j = 0; j < spans.length; j++) {
            var spanText = spans[j].textContent;
            var input = document.createElement('input');
            input.type = 'text';
            input.value = spanText;
            getTds[i].replaceChild(input, spans[j]);
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Error is this code line: spanTexts = getTds[i].getElementsByTag('span'); I think your answer is not correct as its in a loop and I don't want the first span only

Comment: does each `td` have more than one `span` - you need another loop for that

Comment: I see from your next question that each TD has only ONE span - so your first comment above is irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.
It puts the input inside the span

```js
function edit() {
  var span = document.querySelector('.mySpan');
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type='text';
  input.value = span.innerHTML;
  span.innerHTML = '';
  span.appendChild(input)
}
```

```html
<span class="mySpan">this is inside a span</span>
<button onclick="edit()">edit</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to do like this create element and append

```
var text = getTds[i].innerHTML;
getTds[i].innerHTML = "";
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "text";
input.setAttribute('value', text);
getTds[i].getElementsByTagname('span').appendChild(input); // put it into the DOM
```

Comment: that would append to the span, not replace the contents of the span

Comment: This is the error I get: Uncaught TypeError: getTds[i].getElementsByTag is not a function

Comment: @JaromandaX - OP is trying to add one input control for that one need to create control than add innerhtml is not going to work

Comment: @PranayRana - no, he wants to `reach the text inside the span so i can change it to input` - that's CHANGE the contents of the span to be an INPUT, not APPEND an input to the text in span

Comment: @JaromandaX - he wants to replace span text with texbox with the html of span...append adds child to span...

Comment: yes, append adds, thereby keeping the text in there that he wants to replace ... add !== replace

Comment: @JaromandaX my understnaidn is he want to replace span text with input and input value is span text

Comment: @JaromandaX - putting -1 is not going to help because OP not provided clear information..you and undelete your answer and try out...:)

Comment: @PranayRana - while I'm confused by the OP's attempt - yours would not work either, as you'd have `<span>original text<input .... /></span>` - instead of `<input type="text" value="original span text" />` which is probably what he wants

Comment: @PranayRana - I deleted my answer because it was wrong - I also realised that there is SO MUCH WRONG in the original OP code, that only a complete rewrite would do what he wants - if in fact he even knows what he wants

Comment: @PranayRana - what makes you think I voted you down? paranoid much?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82818/discussion-between-pranay-rana-and-jaromanda-x).

Comment: @JaromandaX - same code ....there i no change + span is inside td not inside body element so searching of span as per OP code is also incorrect